# How to Pass NSString Value to Another Property in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods, nsstring

Basically, I have this if statement:

```
NSString *loginResult = [resultsArray valueForKey:@"statusMsg"];
if ([loginResult isEqualToString:@"success"])
{
    [self successDialog]; // Success
}
else 
{
    [self failedDialog]; // Failed
}
```

This is the parsed JSON if success:

```
{"results":{"statusMsg":"success"}}
```

If failed, parsed JSON varies:

```
{"results":{"statusMsg":"password incorrect."}}
```

I want to pass the string value returned by the key **statusMsg** to my alert view inside the failedDialog method. The failedDialog method is defined as:

```
- (void)failedDialog:(NSString *)errorMessage
{
    UIAlertView *dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:kRegFailed
                                                     message:errorMessage
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:kOK
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    dialog.tag = 2;
    [dialog show];  
}
```

How can I do that so that the alert view will have the error message returned. TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wonder why you doing this if your resultsArray is NSArray object

```
NSString *loginResult = [resultsArray valueForKey:@"statusMsg"];
```

Put this in your header file

```
- (void)failedDialog:(NSString *)errorMessage;
```

Try this, suppose your **jsonDict = { "results" :{ "statusMsg" : "password incorrect." } }**

```
[self failedDialog:[NSString stringWithString:[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"results"]objectForKey:@"statusMsg"]]];
```

Comment: What I want is for the failedDialog to receive the message not successDialog.

Comment: sorry i edited the answer, simply changed the method name.. take a look

Comment: I have this warning:
Instance method '-failedDialog:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Comment: what is the warnning? is resultsArray an array or dictionary?

Comment: put this in your header file .h file - (void)failedDialog:(NSString *)errorMessage; answer edited check it

Comment: Thanks. The comment by Prince is what I really wanted. I just forgot to place the right header. Silly me.

Comment: mention not... just to make sure is your last comment in the another answer true?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSString *loginResult = [[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"statusMsg"];
if ([loginResult isEqualToString:@"success"])
{
    [self successDialog]; // Success
}
else 
{
    [self failedDialog:loginResult]; // Failed
}
```

Comment: This is want I want but it returns a warning.

Comment: I implemented the header file change and it worked. I accepted Neo's answer since that led me to what I wanted to achieve.